# Got stuck in httpModule and Promise module

Tags: angular, angular-http

I read this tutorial https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html. I decided to build something totally similar but for support tickets instead of heros.

I have a `TicketService` which gets JSON from a php file.

The code of TicketService is simply this

```
export class TicketService {

private headers     = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
private ticketsUrl  = 'http://localhost/json.php';  // URL to web api

// constructor so that we can get instance of http
constructor(private http: Http) { }


getTickets() : Promise<Ticket[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.ticketsUrl)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json().data as Ticket[])
           .catch(this.handleError)
}

getTicket(id: number): Promise<Ticket> {
    console.log('TicketService getTicket() called: TicketID '+id);
        const url = `${this.ticketsUrl}?${id}`;

    return this.http.get(url)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as Ticket)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

My TicketSystemComponent calls service to get tickets. But even if I print tickets in console they are undefined

```
export class TicketSystemComponent implements OnInit {

    // declare and initialise to empty array
    tickets : Ticket[] = [];

    // This is the only way to get instance of the service
    // https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html [Dependency Injection]
    constructor(private ticketService: TicketService) {
    }

    getTickets() : void {
    console.log('TicketSystemComponent get getTicket()');

    // This line tells that once Service Promise is fullfilled, assigned their tickets to our tickets array
    this.ticketService.getTickets().then(tickets => this.tickets = tickets);

    setTimeout ( function () {
        console.log(this.tickets);
    }, 1000);
    }


    ngOnInit() {

    // We dont call anything slow in constructor. Constructor is not for heavy lifting
    // Get tickets that are already created
    this.getTickets();
    }

}
```

Please check `setTimeout()`, it still has *undefined*. I don't know where I am doing wrong.

JSON output from PHP is simply this

```
[{"category":"Script Support","topic":"Sample Topic 1","url":"http:\/\/www.google.com","details":"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.","fileScreenshot":"none","ticketId":1000,"createdBy":"John"},{"category":"Script Support","topic":"Sample Topic 2","url":"http:\/\/www.google.com","details":"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.","fileScreenshot":"none","ticketId":1001,"createdBy":"John"},{"category":"Script Support","topic":"Sample Topic 3","url":"http:\/\/www.google.com","details":"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.","fileScreenshot":"none","ticketId":1002,"createdBy":"John"}]
```

My `Ticket` class is very simple. This is code of

```
export class Ticket {
    category        :String;
    topic           :String;
    url             :String;
    details         :String;
    fileScreenshot  :String;

    ticketStamp     :number;
    ticketId        :number;
    createdBy       :String;

}
```

Comment: Why are you using promises here??

Comment: The example tutorial on angular.io used promises. Tutorial said that if you use any http request you should use promise so that it is async and does not block your UI. What is best?

Comment: Dont trust tutorials :) check my answer

Comment: Checking your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in service you are not returning *Right* promise

```
 return this.http.get(this.ticketsUrl)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json().data as Ticket[])
           .catch(this.handleError)
```

it means that you handle `then` in your `Service` and by second then in result you will get null since it was handled in first one. Also in your after `response.json()` its your actual json response so there is no data.

You can fix it in multiple ways

**Return value** in promise:

```
return this.http.get(this.ticketsUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => return response.json() as Ticket[])
               .catch(this.handleError)
```

**Rearranging calls**

```
 return this.http.get(this.ticketsUrl)
           .map(response => response.json() as Ticket[])
           .catch(this.handleError)
           .toPromise()
```

Or better **not user promises** here, just user Observable as you expected to:

Service

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

export class TicketService {

    private headers     = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    private ticketsUrl  = 'http://localhost/json.php';  // URL to web api

    // constructor so that we can get instance of http
    constructor(private http: Http) { }


    getTickets() : Observable<Ticket[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.ticketsUrl)
               .map(response => response.json() as Ticket[])
               .catch(this.handleError)
    }

    getTicket(id: number): Observable<Ticket> {
        console.log('TicketService getTicket() called: TicketID '+id);
            const url = `${this.ticketsUrl}?${id}`;

        return this.http.get(url)
            .map(response => response.json() as Ticket)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

Component

```
export class TicketSystemComponent implements OnInit {

    // declare and initialise to empty array
    tickets : Ticket[] = [];

    // This is the only way to get instance of the service
    // https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html [Dependency Injection]
    constructor(private ticketService: TicketService) {
    }

    getTickets() : void {
    console.log('TicketSystemComponent get getTicket()');

    // This line tells that once Service Promise is fullfilled, assigned their tickets to our tickets array
    this.ticketService.getTickets().subscribe(tickets => this.tickets = tickets);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.tickets);
    }, 1000);
    }


    ngOnInit() {

    // We dont call anything slow in constructor. Constructor is not for heavy lifting
    // Get tickets that are already created
    this.getTickets();
    }

}
```

Comment: this function in **Service** named **getTickets** is giving error. Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<Ticket[]>'

Comment: May be function name should be changed to **getTickets() : Observable<Ticket[]> {**

Comment: You need to import it by "import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';" I have updated answer with both import and return type

Comment: Thanks, let me add that.

Comment: It still prints undefined :( in browser Console.

Comment: Because of typescript refference of this let me update answer

Comment: I tried your better method: The one after your line **better not user promises here, just user Observable as you expected to** .... may be my json format is wrong??

Comment: didnt help. I am trying to upload entire code to plunker

Comment: @Sallu remove .data in service just leave response.json()

Comment: Check new service

Comment: It worked. Removing .data worked in the service. Thank you so much.

Comment: property data is angularjs approach :)

Comment: If I may ask, when I should use observable and when promise? do you know how to decide?

Comment: Always use observables they are much more powerful, promises you could use when you integrate with third-party but event then i would use Observable.fromPromise